# Error 4600 Zoho CRM Insert Record using cURL

Tags: php, curl, crm, zoho

Getting Error - 4600 Unable to process your request. Please verify whether you have entered proper method name, parameter and parameter values.

```
$auth="authkey";
$email = $_POST['lowner'];
$firstName = $_POST['fname'];
$lastName = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$url = 'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/insertRecords?';
$post = 'newFormat=1&authtoken='.$auth.'&scope=crmapi&xmlData=<Leads>
<row no="1">
<FL val="Lead Owner">'.$email.'</FL>
<FL val="First Name">'.$firstName.'</FL>
<FL val="Last Name">'.$lastName.'</FL>
<FL val="Email">'.$email.'</FL>
<FL val="Phone">'.$phone.'</FL>
<FL val="Description">Insert ZOHO Lead</FL>
</row>
</Leads>';
//================= start curl ===================
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//================= end curl ===================
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

It supposed to be working fine but you are overriding the email that contains the lead owner variable with other email.

Check the code below:

```
$auth="authkey";
$leadowner = $_POST['lowner'];
$firstName = $_POST['fname'];
$lastName = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$url = 'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/insertRecords?';
$post = 'newFormat=1&authtoken='.$auth.'&scope=crmapi&xmlData=<Leads>
<row no="1">
<FL val="Lead Owner">'.$leadowner.'</FL>
<FL val="First Name">'.$firstName.'</FL>
<FL val="Last Name">'.$lastName.'</FL>
<FL val="Email">'.$email.'</FL>
<FL val="Phone">'.$phone.'</FL>
<FL val="Description">Insert ZOHO Lead</FL>
</row>
</Leads>';
//================= start curl ===================
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//================= end curl ===================
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
exit;
```